# How to parse a list of HTML nodes (with implicit structure) into list of structures

Tags: jquery, xpath, html-parsing

I have a list of logical structures that are represented as a list of flattened nodes

e.g.

```
<div class="start">First Item</div>
<div class="record">First Record</div>
<div class="finish">&nbsp</div>
<div class="start">Second Item</div>
<div class="record">Second Record</div>
<div class="finish">&nbsp</div>
<div class="start">Third Item</div>
<div class="record">Third Record</div>
<div class="finish">&nbsp</div>
```

The task is to parse the list of structures from this flattened list to get something like this.

e.g.

```
[ (First Item, First Record), (Second Item, Second Record), (Third Item, Third Record) ]
```

What is the XPath or JQuery to extract this list of structures?

Comment: Better provide a real life sample HTML if you want a XPath or JQuery snippet

Comment: please define `recover` and relationship of your bogus selectors to real DOM nodes and your expected results

Comment: I can't post the client's HTML in here.

Comment: You can. Add 4 spaces behind each line, or paste all the HTML, select all and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>

Comment: Thanks but I mean I'm not allowed to add my client's HTML to this site.

Comment: HTML can be modified if (strangely) it have secret content. Ex: replace span by naps or anything from your head.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution :

Assume these are css classes

```
  A, B, C, X, A, B, C, X, X, A, B, C
```

This is the code that will extract them as a list of structures

```
$.map( $(".A"), function( n ) {
   console.log ($(n).nextUntil(".C").andSelf())
 });
```

The output will be a list of of lists of nodes (removing the flattening)

```
  (A, B, C), (A, B, C), (A, B, C)
```

Comment: is this your solution or an addendum to the question? If it is an addendum edit the question, don't post as answer

Comment: This is the solution and it won't let me check it as the solution.

Comment: well at least declare it as the solution in the answer text so you don't waste people's time

Comment: You'll be able to select it as answer [after 48 hours](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer).